# chef template variable @node seems to throw error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm going through peepcode's Chef tutorial, so far so good. For some reason there is a failure when using template variables. The example is for nginx.

In the nginx/attributes/nginx.rb I have:

```
default[:nginx][:worker_processes] = 4
```

In the nginx.conf.erb template I refer to:

```
worker_processes  <%= @node[:nginx][:worker_processes] %>;
```

Below is the error I get running chef-solo:

```
Template Context:
-----------------
on line #2
  1: user www-data;
  2: worker_processes  <%= @node[:nginx][:worker_processes] %>;
  3: 
  4: error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  5: pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


[2013-07-14T19:46:36+02:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-07-14T19:46:36+02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2013-07-14T19:46:36+02:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-07-14T19:46:36+02:00] FATAL: Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Other part of the error output:

```
Starting Chef Client, version 11.4.4
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 3 resources
Recipe: nginx::default
  * package[nginx] action install (up to date)
  * service[nginx] action enable (up to date)
  * service[nginx] action start (up to date)
  * template[/etc/nginx/nginx.conf] action create
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/etc/nginx/nginx.conf]'
================================================================================


Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError
------------------------------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /cookbooks/nginx/recipes/default.rb

  8: template "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" do
  9:    notifies :reload, "service[nginx]"
 10: end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /cookbooks/nginx/recipes/default.rb:8:in `from_file'

template("/etc/nginx/nginx.conf") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Template
  action "create"
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  path "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
  backup 5
  source "nginx.conf.erb"
  cookbook_name :nginx
  recipe_name "default"
end
```

Comment: I think this has to do with changes from chef 10 to 11 - attributes are handled slightly differently. Peepcode were created using chef 10 i believe, might try using chef 10 at first and switch to 11 later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access object variables (the ones that start with @) in templates, only if you passed them through `variables` method of template like that:

```
template("/etc/nginx/nginx.conf") do
  [...]
  variables( :my_var => node )
  [...]
end
```

Then you will have `@my_var` available in template. But you don't have to pass the `node`, because it is already available in templates. You just have to access it not as an object variable. The following code in template should work.

```
<%= node[:nginx][:worker_processes] %>
```

Just remove the `@` from the front of `node`.

Comment: in Chef 11 a precedence level must be set. that's the issue. Not @ signs or template variables.

Comment: You are right Draco, sorry for my confusion.  My virtual machine for some reason also wasn't picking up changes correctly. removing the @ sign works now.

Answer (score 2):

The `node` object is not accessible via an instance variable (the thing starting with an @ sign). Instead, it is a method in the current context.

Change:

```
<%= @node[:nginx][:worker_processes] %>
```

to

```
<%= node[:nginx][:worker_processes] %>
```

Notice the removal of the @-sign? You only need the @-sign when passing in variables to the template via the `variables` parameter.

Comment: As I said above, this does not solve the problem; the issue is that in Chef 11 a precedence level must be set as

Comment: for some odd reason it seems to be working now as your stated.  What I was reading in the release notes was about implicit writes, not reads.  So, eating from humble pie after some delay.

Comment: Seth's answer worked for me. As an aside, I mistakenly used `<% = ...` rather than `<%= ...`.